# Two codes of partition function in Scala

Tags: scala

I wrote two versions of function partition for the list.
Below is the correct one:

```
  def partition(list: List[Int],x: Int, head:List[Int], tail:List[Int]): List[Int]= (list.head) match{
        case (a) if a>=x => partition(list.tail,x,head,a::tail)
        case (a) if a<x => partition(list.tail,x,a::head,tail)
        case _ =>head:::tail
        }
```

and may I know why the below code is wrong?

```
def partition(list: List[Int],x: Int, head:List[Int], tail:List[Int]): List[Int]= (list.head) match{
        case _ if _>=x => partition(list.tail,x,head,_::tail)
        case _ if _<x => partition(list.tail,x,_::head,tail)
        case _ =>head:::tail
        }
```

Comment: It's wrong because `_>=x` and `_<x` are functions and not booleans. They won't compile because you don't know the type of `_`. Remember that `_>=x` is the same as `n => n >= x`.

Comment: Btw, did you try to compile this? The error messages are quite clear.

Comment: @marstran yes, I tried, it is wrong, therefore I asked, but why _>=x are functions， _ should represent list.head right?

Comment: `_` does not represent list.head. I don't know where you got that from. `_` is the wild card, and matches everything. `_ >= x` is a function because that is how Scala is defined.

Comment: @marstran for a map [Char, Int]，we can use _._2 to access the int member, right?

Comment: `_._2` is a function. It is equivalent to `x => x._2`. You would use `_._2` inside, for example, the `map` function. The `map` function takes a function as a parameter.